# How to access a method in one object from a second object

Tags: javascript-objects

Hi I'm new to javascript. I have one object ListModel and I am trying to access the addToModel method from a second object.

```
function ListModel(){
    this.list = {};
}

ListModel.prototype.addToModel = function(s){
    var items = s.split("\n");
    for( var i =0; i<items.length-1; i++){
       console.log(items[i] + "\n");
    }
```

}

After extensive searching I have been unable to find a solution to this problem.

The second object is:

```
function ListMaker(){
    this.model = new ListModel();
}

ListMaker.prototype.read = function(e){
   var f = e.target.files[0]; 

   if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
        var contents = e.target.result;
        this.model.addToModel(contents);
        document.getElementById("ta").innerHTML = contents;
     }
       r.readAsText(f);
     } else { 
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
}
```

In the read method I call:
    this.model.addToModel(contents);
and the console returns
Cannot read property 'addToModel' of undefined
If I change the line to:
    this.model = new ListModel().addToModel(contents);
then the method works as excpected.

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *this*

http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Once you call a function, *this* is no longer pointing to what you think it is.

You need to stash *this* in a local and then reference the local in your callback.

```
ListMaker.prototype.read = function(e){
   var f = e.target.files[0]; 
   var _this = this;
   if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
        var contents = e.target.result;
        _this.model.addToModel(contents);
        document.getElementById("ta").innerHTML = contents;
     }
       r.readAsText(f);
     } else { 
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
}
```

See it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZrYQj

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your code runs as expected. But when I apply the changes to my code I get the same error. I will look into the code a bit more, check out the link you gave me and if im still having problems perhaps I could email you the full code.